# How many transactions - Face API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

We are working on a project which groups people at the event. I would like to know how grouping works? Please help me about this situation.

For example, imagine an event with 200 people. And 500 pictures taken at that event. And approximately 3 faces in one picture. Which is total of 1500 faces to identify.

Now, that 200 people registers my site and try to find their photos, how many transactions will Microsoft charge for? 200 x 1500 = 300.000 transactions? How this grouping really works?

Or, the event attenders register to my site by one by. In this situation how will the system work?

Thanks in advance,
T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to identify an individual (as opposed to just a face with age/gender/etc.) you will need to train a classifier, which in the Face API's parlance is a PersonGroup.  You would have one PersonGroup, consisting of 200 Persons.  Each Person should register with (ideally multiple) Face images.  Assuming registrants provided 2 face images, you so far have 1 (`CreatePersonGroup`) + 200 (`CreatePerson`) + 2 * 200 (`AddPersonFace`) + 1 (`TrainPersonGroup`) = 602 transactions.

For each event photo, you would call `Detect` to get a list of face Ids.  Then you will feed the face Ids to the `Identify` call.  So that's another 2 * 500 transactions.  (Note here that Identify can take up to 10 faces per request, whereas Detect may return up to 64 faces, so you may, depending on the photo, have to call Identify more than once per event photo.)

Overall where talking ~1.6K transactions.